# Peculiar way for object creation?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, malloc, new-operator

Here is an example of implementing a class for creating objects:

```
template <class T>
struct MallocCreator {
    static T* Create() {
        void* buf = std::malloc(sizeof(T));
        if (!buf) return 0;
        return new(buf) T;
    }
};
```

by using `malloc` and the `new` operator.

What is the role of `new` and what exactly is the above syntax?

Comment: [Placement new operator](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new)

Comment: @101010 Why not returning the pointer from `malloc` directly?

Comment: More than likely because `malloc` does not call the constructor.

Comment: Because then all you would have is a block of allocated memory but no object will have been initialized.

Comment: Here's to hoping you're not also responsible for calling `free` yourself. If I received an object like that in C++, and the onus of memory management was on me, I'd stupidly call `delete` instead.

Comment: @AndyG so, to free an object created from the above class, one should use `object->~T();`, right ?

Comment: @simplicisveritatis Yes. That calls the destructor. After that  you should also call `std::free(object);` to deallocate the memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's ["placement new"](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new). What your code does is to create raw memory for the size of one `T` with `malloc` and then construct a new `T` in that raw memory.

Answer (score 2):

`new(buf) MyObject` is the placement-new-operator.

It basically is saying, `buf` is some memory I've allocate for the object, and I want C++ to create the object in that memory.  (Conventional `new` will both allocate memory and construct an object.)

It appears that whoever wrote this code is trying to return `NULL` in case of an allocation problem, where "conventional" new throws an exception (`std::badalloc`) if there is a problem during allocation.

It is generally my experience that devs not comfortable with exception handling, would rather check for `NULL` than catch an exception.

Comment: "devs not comfortable with exception handling" should become comfortable with it. Not to mention that there is also `std::nothrow`!

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I'm not disagreeing with you at all.   I've just observed many people who check for NULL after every `new` statement, and don't understand that is literally an impossible condition.

Answer (score 1):

This is a placement new used there: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Firstly, this code is allocating memory through malloc, and then constructs object inside allocated memory.